# How can I implement BorshDeserialize on struct with a string?

Tags: string, serialization, rust, deserialization, solana

When trying to build by Solana Program, I'm getting this error. Can anybody please tell me how can I serialize String, As I'm using String in my struct. OR instead of String what I should I use if serializing string isn't possible in Solana program?

*Struct: Box*

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug, BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, PartialEq)]
pub struct Box {
    pub token_uris: [String; 3], 
    pub count: i32,
    pub title: String,
    pub description: String,
    pub image: String,
    pub price: i32,
    pub usd_price: i32,
    pub count_nft: i32,
    pub is_opened: bool,
}
```

*Error Log:*

```
15 | #[derive(Clone, Debug, BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, PartialEq)]
   |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::marker::Copy` is not implemented for `std::string::String`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `AnchorDeserialize` for `[std::string::String; 3]`
   = help: see issue #48214
   = note: this error originates in the derive macro `BorshDeserialize` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Comment: Can you post a mre of the issue?

Comment: Hi @Netwave not sure what you mean by mre , do you mean to post "struct" causing this issue ? just added it to my question, please check

Comment: MRE = [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), a way for would-be helpers to not have to invent or intuit things which may or may not have any relationship to the issue at hand. The process of creating an MRE can also often lead the would-be asker to find the answer to their request as it requires better understanding the error conditions and what is happening.

Comment: Calling your structure 'Box' is not ideal as `Box` has an inherent Rust definition

Comment: Right I'd fixed it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anybody please tell me how can I serialize String, As I'm using String in my struct.

The problem is not that you're using a string, or a string in a struct, it's that you're using a string *in a fixed-size array*, hence the compiler pointing to that specifically:

```
for `[std::string::String; 3]`
```

not

```
for `String`
```

And if you go read [the documentation for `BorshDeserialize`](https://docs.rs/borsh/0.9.1/borsh/de/trait.BorshDeserialize.html) you can find:

```rust
impl<T> BorshDeserialize for [T; 3] where
    T: BorshDeserialize + Default + Copy,
```

So `BorshDeserialize` is only implemented for arrays `Default + Copy` types. Since a `String` is not `Copy` the automatic derivation can not work.

The fixes are to either:

- not use a fixed-size array
- or implement `BorshDeserialize` by hand on your structure instead of trying to `derive()` it

Comment: Thanks @Masking It really helped me to understand the issue, I can confirm it wasn't issue of using String in Struct but using String in array. 
But I need to store Strings in array what can I do ? compiler suggesting to use 
```alloc::boxed::Box; ``` as 
```
token_uris: Box<[String]>

```
is it efficient way to store strings in array or there's anyother way as well ?

Comment: " But I need to store Strings in array what can I do ?" as I told you, implement the deserialiser manually instead of deriving it

Comment: "compiler suggesting to use alloc::boxed::Box; as ``` token_uris: Box<[String]> ``` is it efficient way to store strings in array or there's anyother way as well ?" it's completely useless since `derive(BorshDeserialiser)` *still will not work*. It can't work wiith a `[String;3]`, doesn't matter if you put it in a `Box`, won't work any better.